# Replacing NaNs in a dataframe with a string value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, missing-data

I want to replace the missing value in one column of my df with "missing value".
I tried

```
result['emp_title'].fillna('missing')
```

or

```
result['emp_title'] = result['emp_title'].replace({ np.nan:'missing'})
```

the second one works, since when i count missing value after this code:

```
result['emp_title'].isnull().sum()
```

it gave me 0.
However, the first one does not work as I expected, which did not give me a 0, instead of the previous count for missing value.
Why the first one does not work? Thank you!

Comment: `result['emp_title'] = result['emp_title'].fillna('missing')` because it doesn't replace values `in place` - it returns a new series

Comment: or `result['emp_title'].fillna('missing',inplace=true)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to fill inplace, or assign:

```
result['emp_title'].fillna('missing', inplace=True)
```

or

```
result['emp_title'] = result['emp_title'].fillna('missing')
```

---

MVCE:

```
In [1697]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : [1, 2, 3, np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan]})

In [1702]: df.fillna('missing'); df # changes not seen in the original
Out[1702]: 
   Col1
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
3   NaN
4   4.0
5   5.0
6   NaN

In [1703]: df.fillna('missing', inplace=True); df
Out[1703]: 
      Col1
0        1
1        2
2        3
3  missing
4        4
5        5
6  missing
```

You should be aware that if you are trying to apply `fillna` to slices, don't use `inplace=True`, instead, use `df.loc/iloc` and assign to sub-slices:

```
In [1707]: df.Col1.iloc[:5].fillna('missing', inplace=True); df # doesn't work
Out[1707]: 
   Col1
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
3   NaN
4   4.0
5   5.0
6   NaN

In [1709]: df.Col1.iloc[:5] = df.Col1.iloc[:5].fillna('missing')

In [1710]: df
Out[1710]: 
      Col1
0        1
1        2
2        3
3  missing
4        4
5        5
6      NaN
```